# Python (3.6.4) - Creating a Random Quiz

Tags: python, random

```
#! python3
# randomQuizGenerator.py - Creates quizzes with questions and answers in
# random order, along with the answer key

import random

#the quiz data. Keys are states and values are their capitals.

capitals = {'Alabama': 'Montgomery', 'Alaska': 'Juneau', 'Arizona': 'Phoenix', 'Arkansas': 'Little Rock', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Colorado': 'Denver', 'Connecticut': 'Hartford', 'Delaware': 'Dover', 'Florida': 'Tallahassee', 'Georgia': 'Atlanta', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu', 'Idaho': 'Boise', 'Illinois':'Springfield', 'Indiana': 'Indianapolis', 'Iowa': 'Des Moines', 'Kansas': 'Topeka', 'Kentucky': 'Frankfort', 'Louisiana': 'Baton Rouge', 'Maine': 'Augusta', 'Maryland': 'Annapolis', 'Massachusetts': 'Boston', 'Michigan':'Lansing', 'Minnesota': 'Saint Paul', 'Mississippi': 'Jackson', 'Missouri': 'Jefferson City', 'Montana': 'Helena', 'Nebraska': 'Lincoln', 'Nevada':'Carson City', 'New Hampshire': 'Concord', 'New Jersey': 'Trenton', 'New Mexico': 'Santa Fe', 'New York': 'Albany', 'North Carolina': 'Raleigh','North Dakota': 'Bismarck', 'Ohio': 'Columbus', 'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City','Oregon': 'Salem', 'Pennsylvania': 'Harrisburg', 'Rhode Island': 'Providence','South Carolina': 'Columbia', 'South Dakota': 'Pierre', 'Tennessee':'Nashville', 'Texas': 'Austin', 'Utah': 'Salt Lake City', 'Vermont':'Montpelier', 'Virginia': 'Richmond', 'Washington': 'Olympia', 'West Virginia': 'Charleston', 'Wisconsin': 'Madison', 'Wyoming': 'Cheyenne'}

#Generate 35 quiz files
for quizNum in range(35):
    #Create the quiz and answer the key files.
    quizFile = open('capitalsquiz%s.txt' % (quizNum + 1), 'w')
    answerKeyFile = open('capitalsquiz_answers%s.txt' % (quizNum + 1), 'w')

    #Write out the header for the quiz.
    quizFile.write('Name:\n\nDate:\n\nPeriod:\n\n')
    quizFile.write((' ' *20) + 'State Capitals Quiz (Form %s)' % (quizNum + 1))
    quizFile.write('\n\n')

    #Shuffle the order of the states.
    states = list(capitals.keys())
    random.shuffle(states)


    #Loop through all 50 states, making a question for each.
for questionNum in range(50):

    #get right and wrong answers
    correctAnswer = capitals[states[questionNum]]
    wrongAnswers = list(capitals.values())
    del wrongAnswers[wrongAnswers.index(correctAnswer)]
    wrongAnswers = random.sample(wrongAnswers, 3)
    answerOptions = wrongAnswers + [correctAnswer]
    random.shuffle(answerOptions)

    #write the question and the answer options to the quiz file.
    quizFile.write('%s. What is the capital of %s?\n' % (questionNum + 1,
            states[questionNum]))
    for i in range(4):
        quizFile.write('   %s.  %s\n' % ('ABCD'[i], answerOptions[i]))
        quizFile.write('\n')

     # Write the answer key to a file.
answerKeyFile.write('%s. %s\n' % (questionNum + 1, 'ABCD'[
    answerOptions.index(correctAnswer)]))

quizFile.close()
answerKeyFile.close()
```

When I run the program the questions and answers don't get generated. Am I experiencing a formatting issue? The goal is to create 35 quizzes, 4 questions and answers in each. Somehow the only thing that appears is just the header for the quiz and nothing else below that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the indentation of your second for loop Try so :

```
        #! python3
    # randomQuizGenerator.py - Creates quizzes with questions and answers in
    # random order, along with the answer key

import random

#the quiz data. Keys are states and values are their capitals.

capitals = {'Alabama': 'Montgomery', 'Alaska': 'Juneau', 'Arizona': 'Phoenix', 'Arkansas': 'Little Rock', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Colorado': 'Denver', 'Connecticut': 'Hartford', 'Delaware': 'Dover', 'Florida': 'Tallahassee', 'Georgia': 'Atlanta', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu', 'Idaho': 'Boise', 'Illinois':'Springfield', 'Indiana': 'Indianapolis', 'Iowa': 'Des Moines', 'Kansas': 'Topeka', 'Kentucky': 'Frankfort', 'Louisiana': 'Baton Rouge', 'Maine': 'Augusta', 'Maryland': 'Annapolis', 'Massachusetts': 'Boston', 'Michigan':'Lansing', 'Minnesota': 'Saint Paul', 'Mississippi': 'Jackson', 'Missouri': 'Jefferson City', 'Montana': 'Helena', 'Nebraska': 'Lincoln', 'Nevada':'Carson City', 'New Hampshire': 'Concord', 'New Jersey': 'Trenton', 'New Mexico': 'Santa Fe', 'New York': 'Albany', 'North Carolina': 'Raleigh','North Dakota': 'Bismarck', 'Ohio': 'Columbus', 'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City','Oregon': 'Salem', 'Pennsylvania': 'Harrisburg', 'Rhode Island': 'Providence','South Carolina': 'Columbia', 'South Dakota': 'Pierre', 'Tennessee':'Nashville', 'Texas': 'Austin', 'Utah': 'Salt Lake City', 'Vermont':'Montpelier', 'Virginia': 'Richmond', 'Washington': 'Olympia', 'West Virginia': 'Charleston', 'Wisconsin': 'Madison', 'Wyoming': 'Cheyenne'}

#Generate 35 quiz files
for quizNum in range(35):
    #Create the quiz and answer the key files.
    quizFile = open('capitalsquiz%s.txt' % (quizNum + 1), 'w')
    answerKeyFile = open('capitalsquiz_answers%s.txt' % (quizNum + 1), 'w')

    #Write out the header for the quiz.
    quizFile.write('Name:\n\nDate:\n\nPeriod:\n\n')
    quizFile.write((' ' *20) + 'State Capitals Quiz (Form %s)' % (quizNum + 1))
    quizFile.write('\n\n')

    #Shuffle the order of the states.
    states = list(capitals.keys())
    random.shuffle(states)


        #Loop through all 50 states, making a question for each.
    for questionNum in range(50):

        #get right and wrong answers
        correctAnswer = capitals[states[questionNum]]
        wrongAnswers = list(capitals.values())
        del wrongAnswers[wrongAnswers.index(correctAnswer)]
        wrongAnswers = random.sample(wrongAnswers, 3)
        answerOptions = wrongAnswers + [correctAnswer]
        random.shuffle(answerOptions)
        print questionNum,quizFile
        # ui
        #write the question and the answer options to the quiz file.
        quizFile.write('%s. What is the capital of %s?\n' % (questionNum + 1,
                states[questionNum]))
        for i in range(4):
            quizFile.write('   %s.  %s\n' % ('ABCD'[i], answerOptions[i]))
            quizFile.write('\n')

     # Write the answer key to a file.
        answerKeyFile.write('%s. %s\n' % (questionNum + 1, 'ABCD'[answerOptions.index(correctAnswer)]))

quizFile.close()
answerKeyFile.close()
```